# Unable to reference value of dynamically added/changed input boxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Okay, what am I missing?

I'm currently trying to generate a clone of certain elements in a project - which works fine, as long as nothing is updated.

The problem is that if any of the input boxes are changed, or any new boxes added or removed dynamically, the data in the field (value) doesn't seem to persist.

e.g. running:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input placeholder="placeholder"/>
    <input placeholder="placeholder" value="change me"/>
    <button class="output">
      do log
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.output', function () {
        const htmlCopy = $('html').clone();
    
    htmlCopy.find('input').each((i, inp) => {
        console.log(inp);
        //console.log(inp.value) does work - but I need the entire element for the clone below
    })
    
    //Do stuff with clone
})
```

Will log any previous or new input elements (great!) but the value is either the original data or just empty respectively (not so great).

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here that I can't quite crack last thing on a Friday afternoon.

Grabbing stuff `.on(change)` seems to work, but I need all of those up to date values on a button click.

I've tired executing things in different orders and referencing (and then assigning) the value in slightly other ways, but it feels like a simple answer is largely just staring me in the face.

Comment: You should include the inputs your are attempting to clone; we need a complete minimal reproducible example to be able to recreate your problem.

Comment: Your `console.log()` should be `console.log(inp.value)` probably.

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with the code you posted in the question. The jQuery library is not broken, and neither is your browser. Is that *really* your code? Have you actually tried the posted code in your application to see if it works?

Comment: Apologies @mykaf : here's a very quick demo. 

https://jsfiddle.net/rkLgsqv0/

Comment: Please add your code here, just enough to show the whole problem. Links can break and are then no help to future readers.

Comment: Slightly better example above @mykaf

Comment: Slightly better example above @Pointy

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what's supposed to happen, your full example seems to work for me; when I update both inputs' values, both new values are logged.

Comment: Are you saying that you expect the value to be the same in the cloned inputs?  It will not match the attribute as that is only a starting value, and each is maintained separately.  The attribute on the html is not updated as the value (data) changes - that's held in memory.

Comment: Essentially, when I click the button I need the cloned html element to contain all of the new/changed data that exists in the current inputs. As it stands, the clone just contains the same data as when the file loaded (+ new (empty) elements).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, when you're working off the `value` of input boxes, make sure you're actually keeping the value up to date with what's in the box. I got my clone to stay up to date with the current state of the page by throwing this in:

```
$(document).on("input", "input", function(e) {
    $(this).attr('value', e.target.value);
})
```